# How to remove empty column in JasperReport CSV file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-csv

trying to make a csv file generated from pdf with the help of JasperReport. Generated successfully, but empty column for the first pdf page.

6 columns in total (A / C Number Address Client Name Telephone no. Email Contact Date), but for the first page 7 (A / C Number Address **blank** Client Name Telephone no. Email Contact Date)

And I can't find the reason for this behavior.

Update:
Here possible reasons for csv difference in column name for first and next pages
[image]

**Difference in one extra comma**

Here is template:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports 
  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
          name="clients_without_cleaners" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" 
orientation="Landscape"
          whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" 
rightMargin="20" topMargin="20"
          bottomMargin="20" uuid="285cc266-e2fa-4882-a9dd-ae24c41a7937"
          scriptletClass="rsoft.utile.JrxmlUtil">

<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="clientName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[clientName]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="telephone" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[telephone]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="email" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[email]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="contactDate" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[contactDate]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="address" class="rsoft.model.api.internal.item.AddressItem">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[address]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="69" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="240" y="35" width="321" height="20" uuid="cb5fc5c6-d061-4440-a09d-a254af721eec"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Clients]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="240" y="0" width="321" height="35" uuid="8497420b-8644-483c-a187-d4cca1fd7263"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Test]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="447" y="10" width="112" height="20" uuid="546aff27-dfe6-48b3-855c-7e35f07c0d61"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Telephone no.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="167" y="10" width="100" height="20" uuid="96af720b-2439-433d-a672-46ea146538a3"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="691" y="10" width="100" height="20" uuid="43b56b3e-e87f-4ebb-a719-ba3223560cc7"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Contact Date]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="28" y="10" width="100" height="20" uuid="1ce9f9cd-c5d2-4d0b-93c3-60157b95703a"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[A/C Number]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="316" y="10" width="106" height="20" uuid="879f44fa-e4fe-42e7-b741-ec3baeada4df"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Client Name]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="579" y="10" width="84" height="20" uuid="3b743c11-bd3f-4e97-8cad-fa21158eff7a"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Email]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="51" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="28" y="0" width="100" height="11" uuid="c38ba780-a11f-4043-ae54-c2bb602d89a4"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="447" y="0" width="100" height="11" uuid="d503aa89-744f-424f-a3d9-c3b769846c74"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{telephone}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="167" y="0" width="117" height="51" uuid="635f99c3-c25a-4963-aa2a-54fac292bfe5"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getAddress($F{address})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="316" y="0" width="100" height="11" uuid="c7879229-e64c-47de-a61f-346397509d3c"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{clientName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="691" y="0" width="100" height="11" uuid="c9ae56cc-5649-4ab5-9dad-00aef9e0aba6"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{contactDate}.isEmpty() ? "N/A" : $F{contactDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="579" y="0" width="100" height="11" uuid="500b890b-491c-473d-913d-952ac889d34d"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="51"
                           uuid="0dd2be3d-b87e-4cf5-8669-243a58f6e180"/>
        </rectangle>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
<noData>
    <band height="50">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="28" y="13" width="204" height="20" uuid="75bdf542-21b3-401a-886d-c907d71436ab"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[No details found]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</noData>
```

So first of all pdf is generated

```
@Override
public JasperPrint getPDF(GetPdfReportReq getPdfReportReq) throws JRException {
    List list = null;
    String sourceFileName = null;
    GetReportReq getReportReq = new GetReportReq(getPdfReportReq);
                    sourceFileName = getClass().getClassLoader()
                            .getResource("jasper_reports/clients_without_cleaners.jrxml").getFile();
          
            list = jobDao.getClientsForReports(getReportReq, true).stream().map(item -> new ClientReportItem(item,
                    ClientsReportType.getById(Integer.parseInt(getReportReq.getReportType())))).collect(Collectors.toList());
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource =
            new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);

    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    try {
        return JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sourceFileName), parameters, beanColDataSource);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then I make a csv file from pdf

```
   response.setContentType("application/csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".csv");
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        JRCsvExporter exporter = new JRCsvExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(pdfExportService.getPDF(getPdfReportReq)));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(response.getOutputStream()));
        SimpleCsvReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleCsvReportConfiguration();
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporter.exportReport();

        response.flushBuffer();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
    }
}
```

So the problem is that for the first page, an empty column is displayed after the address
Example of pdf

[image]

Example of CSV

[image]

Problem is for the first page of PDF, but for PDF it's correct in view, but when it is mapping for  CSV it has an empty column.

I think the problem is in the double comma, but I don't know what is responsible for the comma in the template

[image]

Comment: Why do you want some rows to have NON blank `,,` columns, while later rows have populated columns.  That doesn't make much sense for CSV files.  That `,,` should be resolved to a `null` in whatever program you're inputting it to.  But that looks like exactly what I would expect from your PD F output.

Comment: I do not want some columns to be empty, I just want to remove the extra column for the first pdf page
6 columns in total, but for the first page 7 (including one blank)

Comment: Here is possible reason https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVKVv.png
Difference in one extra comma

Comment: Right on, sorry I didn't notice that at first.  Glad you got it resolved!

Answer (score 0):

The extra comma (empty column) was due to the fact that the pdf file had a name and it was contained in the title tag, deleting this title and creating a special template for csv solved my problem.

```
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="248" y="35" width="321" height="20" uuid="a2307aa1-17a7-4118-9d91-8a7cdbfc3294"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Test]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="248" y="0" width="321" height="35" uuid="549c8c0b-a978-4fec-b998-a176e2a44047"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Test]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
```

As I understood at the time of reading from pdf, jasper took into account this tag and its dimensions and considered it necessary to add an empty column for the first page.